# Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem

Tags: git, repository, remote-server, delete-file, git-rm

I want to remove a file from my repository.

```
git rm file_to_remove.txt
```

will remove the file from the repository, but it will also remove the file from the local file system. How do I remove this file from the repo **without** deleting my local copy of the file?

Comment: Duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: It's worth noting that the most upvoted answer is dangerous for some. If you are using a remote repo than when you push your local then pull elsewhere those files you removed from git only *WILL BE DELETED*. This is mentioned in one of the replies but not commented upon.

Comment: to do it the right way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418769/definitive-retroactive-gitignore-how-to-make-git-completely-retroactively-forg/

Comment: Critical warning: Please read this answer before pasting accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67793572/6073148

Comment: @goofology As far as I can see that linked question has no accepted answer. So what is the right way to do this??

Comment: As you can see, there are many different variations depending on the desired end result and ramifications that apply to a public/shared repo vs private. Regarding the linked question, I assume both answers work - the one with most upvotes is mine, but the accepted answer uses a new method that did not exist when I wrote my solution.  I have not tried the accepted answer.

Comment: @Zahid Khan 6 years into my career and I still haven't learned to read before I run the command. lol at least this was just junk data, in my case.

Answer (score 5440, accepted):

The [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) documentation states:

> When `--cached` is given, the staged content has to match either the tip of the branch or the file on disk, allowing the file to be removed from just the index.

So, for a single file:

```
git rm --cached file_to_remove.txt
```

and for a single directory:

```
git rm --cached -r directory_to_remove
```

Comment: Easily missed because it is not as self explanatory as `svn rm --keep-local`.

Comment: But how do I preserve the files on remote servers? This keeps my local one, but if I push and pull from another server, the file gets deleted. I also added a .gitignore for the file, but it still get's removed

Comment: This still removes the files on `git pull` if you are behind the commit after `git rm`

Comment: Maybe instead of `git rm --cached mylogfile.log` it should be `git rm --unstage mylogfile.log` for more clearance.

Comment: By switching to other branch, file is removed.

Comment: Worth noting that, after running the command in the answer, you need to use `git commit -m "Commit message"` and `git push`. If you have any other staged changes (check with `git status`), they will also be committed at this time.

Comment: Since this is the most accepted answer and doesn't do, what is asked for, i'll tell what I do. I use the command `git rm --cached mylogfile.log` and delete the file from the repository. To avoid losing the file on productive system i do a backup of the file and pull after this. The file get's deleted as mentioned before and need to be copied back from your backup. This is quite a pain, but i found no better solution for this problem.

Comment: For those that have missed in the question that the OP already added to .gitignore, please note that that's a necessary step to make sure the local file isn't deleted during a later merge or pull. You might find this answer helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32182114/1024735

Comment: Wow, the language in that man page entry is super convoluted. -- I could have read it three times and not realized that it was related to this topic.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 That's git for ya!

Comment: Warning: if you use this method, the files WILL be deleted from any other clones of the same repo. They will ONLY be preserved on your local installation. For example, if you have a live production server and a local development server, removing from cached will affect your production server.

Answer (score 327):

To remove an entire folder from the repo (like Resharper files), do this:

```
git rm -r --cached folderName
```

I had committed some resharper files, and did not want those to persist for other project users.

Comment: Just an added note for future visitors: Don't use a GUI to "Sync" the commit back to the repo. That will pull the files back down into your local repo. You have to do a `Git Push repo branch` to actually remove the files from the remote.

Answer (score 303):

To remove files from the repository based on `.gitignore`, without deleting them from the local file system:

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i -c -X .gitignore`
```

For Windows Powershell:

```
git rm --cached $(git ls-files -i -c -X .gitignore)
```

Comment: Does not work on Windows. git ls-files -i -X .gitignore works, but I dont know how to send the files to 'git rm'. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Works on Windows if you use Git Bash instead of cmd-console

Comment: Love this.  Worked except that I had some files that ended up having spaces in filename.  I modified solution here to this: `git ls-files -i -X .gitignore | xargs -I{} git rm --cached "{}"`.  Please consider modifying or adding this solution to the answer here, because it is a great tool to have...

Comment: I didn't try but it should be tested will it remove also files like `.gitkeep` which preserves an empty folder in repository. Eg. `.gitignore` contain folder `uploads` and repo is forced to keep track of `.gitkeep`. By removing all from repo under `uploads` it will remove also `.gitkeep`.

Comment: This suggestion worked perfectly in powershell: git rm --cached $(git ls-files -i -X .gitignore)

Comment: If the `.gitignore` in subdirectories shall be evaluated as well, use `--exclude-per-directory` instead of `-X`.

Comment: In CMD, use a for:
`for /f %x in ('git ls-files -i -X .gitignore') do git rm --cached %x`

Comment: Does not work e.g. with git version 2.35.1:
`git ls-files -i -X .gitignore` results in
`fatal: ls-files -i must be used with either -o or -c`

Comment: What works for me is `-c`: `git rm --cached $(git ls-files -i -c -X .gitignore)`

Answer (score 130):

As per my Answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27271913/3540289)

#### To remove folder/directory or file only from git repository and not from the local try 3 simple steps.

---

**Steps to remove directory**

```
git rm -r --cached File-or-FolderName
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository"
git push origin master
```

---

**Steps to ignore that folder in next commits**

> To ignore that folder from next commits make one file in root named **.gitignore**
> and put that folders name into it. You can put as many as you want

**.gitignore** file will be look like this

```
/FolderName
```

---

[image: remove directory]

Comment: Will this delete other people's local files when they pull down your changes though?

Answer (score 82):

A more generic solution:

1. Edit `.gitignore` file.

   `echo mylogfile.log >> .gitignore`
2. Remove all items from index.

   `git rm -r -f --cached .`
3. Rebuild index.

   `git add .`
4. Make new commit

   `git commit -m "Removed mylogfile.log"`

Comment: Will this actually delete the file ?

Comment: From GitHub? NO. If you have already pushed to github it will not remove it from the site. But it will update your local git repository.

Comment: The comment you deleted was more eliminated actually :) The problem with the solution `rm --cashed` is that it will eventually delete the file when one pulls - right ? And this is not what people want when they say "Remove a file from the repository _without deleting it from the local filesystem_". Now why was the solution above accepted is beyond me - probably the OP was working alone and never pulled ? Dunno. I understand the github "once pushed always there" issue ofc

Comment: I don't think there is a 100% solution unless you ask github itself. For now stick to this. Copy file, Add to gitignore, do actual git rm -r, commit, push, restore file. Did you manage to find another solution?

Comment: My problem is not github - it is that _the file will actually be deleted from coworkers when they pull_. I _don't_ want the file to be deleted. This has caused me huge issues in the past. So I was wondering if there is really a solution that really _does not_ delete the file. See also the comment inn the accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy/20565682?noredirect=1#comment21117138_1143800

Comment: Sorry man. I'm stumped. Option 1. inlude a download script that adds files after a pull. Option 2. Configure `git update-index --assume-unchanged` instead of `git rm`.

Comment: Since I'm terrified about destroying data, this answer would be better if it explicitly said whether or not mylogfile.log will be deleted locally at any of those steps.

Answer (score 76):

Also, if you have commited sensitive data (e.g. a file containing passwords), you should completely delete it from the history of the repository.  Here's a guide explaining how to do that:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: This answer should include the required commands to complete this task instead of linking to another website.

Comment: I would also note that I found using the [git bfg repo cleaner tool](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) easier and faster.

Comment: Link is dead, which is why you always put the information in your post instead of just linking to external sites.

Comment: @CapinWinky Thanks for the heads-up, I've updated the answer with current URL (can't really put all the information in the answer though, it's quite a long article).

Answer (score 29):

> Git lets you ignore those files by assuming they are unchanged. This
>   is done by running the `git update-index --assume-unchanged
>   path/to/file.txt` command. Once marking a file as such, git will
>   completely ignore any changes on that file; they will not show up when
>   running git status or git diff, nor will they ever be committed.

(From https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Hence, not deleting it, but ignoring changes to it forever.
I think this only works locally, so co-workers can still see changes to it unless they run the same command as above. (Still need to verify this though.)

Note: This isn't answering the question directly, but is based on follow up questions in the comments of the other answers.

Comment: Hm, I do this but I see that the file can be overwritten if someone else makes changes to it on the repo.

Comment: This is SUPER dangerous, as any conflicts in such file would prevent you from checking out, while `assume` locks you out from fixing the conflicts.

Comment: @Agent_L Would running `--no-assume-unchanged` kind of revert it? Just have to save the file somewhere before doing so? I'm curious because I have database settings files ignored in my local and haven't encountered the situation you described, though I might just be nuking it and just recreating it when I did encounter problems so it was a non-issue for me.

Comment: @Rystraum yeah, that's what I had to. Unasume, and resolve conflict. Or force checkout. If your database setting don't change in your origin that would explain lack of conflicts.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to just **untrack** a file and **not delete** from local and remote repo then use this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  file_name_with_path
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, it's important to note this doesn't "untrack" a file in the sense that people usually use that word with Git, where an untracked file is one that isn't in the repository history and never has been. What this answer does is keep the file in the repository but prevent Git from noticing that changes have been made to it. That has some significant differences -- most importantly, the file is still present for others, and if someone else makes changes to it and you pull, your local copy can be overwritten without confirmation.

Answer (score 18):

### Ignore the files, remove the files from git, update git (for the removal).

*Note : this does not deal with history for sensitive information.*

This process definitely takes some undertanding of what is going on with git.  Over time, having gained that, I've learned to do processes such as:

#### 1) Ignore the files

- Add or update the project `.gitignore` to ignore them - in many cases such as yours, the parent directory, e.g. `log/` will be the regex to use.
- commit and push that `.gitignore` file change (not sure if push needed mind you, no harm if done).

#### 2) Remove the files from git (only).

- Now remove the files from git (only) with `git rm --cached some_dir/`
- Check that they still remain locally (they should!).

#### 3) Add and commit that change (essentially this is a change to "add" deleting stuff, despite the otherwise confusing "add" command!)

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m"removal"`

Comment: see this questions for details of why this is a bad answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57418769/definitive-retroactive-gitignore-how-to-make-git-completely-retroactively-forg/

Comment: @IlyaKolesnikov I looked at that answer and this answer addresses most of the concerns that is raises by using step 3 to commit the deletion change.

Answer (score 8):

Above answers didn't work for me. I used `filter-branch` to remove all committed files.

Remove a file  from a git repository with:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm  file'
```

Remove a folder from a git repository with:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf directory'
```

This removes the directory or file from all the commits.

You can specify a commit by using:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf directory' HEAD
```

Or an range:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf vendor/gems' t49dse..HEAD
```

To push everything to remote, you can do:

```
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: This combined with `git rm -r --cached NAME` is the trick to remove it from your local git repo and prevent it from affecting anyone who pulls later (by deleting history of the file or directory from git.)

Comment: This rewrites git history and you would need to push --force after, this is a bit out of scope with the question I guess. On a public famous repo you can't just change the history line like that as everyone having already cloned the repo would get issues when pulling.

Comment: From the man page "git filter-branch has a plethora of pitfalls .... Please use an alternative history filtering tool such as git filter-repo". Also, if you are going to rewrite history, I guess you could modify the ignore file at an early age so that the removed item(s) are ignored throughout the new history?

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add to the accepted answer of [@bdonlan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143800/6073148).

---

##### DON'T USE THIS ANSWER TO REMOVE FILE(S) THAT EXISTS ON REMOTE.

```
git rm --cached filename
```

---

#### What the answer is supposed to do?

It is supposed to remove some files from the local staged area that you have mistakenly committed in some previous commit(s).

1. And have not pushed to the remote.
2. And if pushed on remote, others don't care about those changes.

It moves files from **Tracked**  **Untracked** state by that what I mean is, it *deletes* the files and *adds* them again.

So, git doesn't know about them anymore.

---

### What could go wrong?

On remote, there is  such thing as an  , there is    and that results in havoc.

---

### Why?

When collaborating with the team, if you  such changes up to remote it will delete those changes on remote and all the team who takes a  from               .

**Summary**: You removed files from staged and then pushed them will result in the deletion of files on the collaborating team's local repository as well (         ,     will be . )

Comment: Without an alternate solution, this is a (very important) comment but not an answer.

Comment: But, doesn't git keep a history to this file? I mean, we could always revert back?

Comment: @RaynalGobel yes `git` has all the history available and you can revert back anytime. But the thing is should you do it? Like you delete your collaborator's file while you have that file available locally?

In my case, the lead trusts me and merges my PR blindly. The application wasn't working on his machine while it was working on mine. Think about this scenario!

Comment: Agree with @BrianZ, this is a very important *comment*. It would be nice to complete it with a suggestion of the right way to do it!

Comment: The OP's question is precisely about removing a file from the Repo. I think this answer is out of place.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you mean by 'remove' from git. :)

You can unstage a file using git rm --cached [see for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308136/what-is-git-cache-and-what-is-stored-in-the-git-cache). When you unstage something, it means that it is no longer tracked, but this does not remove the file from previous commits.

If you want to do more than unstage the file, for example to remove sensitive data from all previous commits you will want to look into filtering the branch using tools like the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#purging-a-file-from-your-repositorys-history).

Answer (score 1):

since `rm --cache` will delete files in the remote repository, you could use `update-index` instead
see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/ignore-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 1):

I used the following simple method to remove some IDE-related files from git as they made the repo look cluttered.

**Note:** This doesn't remove them from the git history.

**Note:** If you've accidentially committed passwords the first thing to do is change those passwords.

- Commit or revert any local changes.
- Backup the files locally to another folder.
- Remove the files from your local repo.
- Commit the change where the files are removed.
- Edit your .gitignore file to list the files/folders.
- Copy the files locally back into their original location.
- Run `git status` and check that the files are not listed.
- Commit the change to .gitignore

Comment: But when contributors pull your change their local version of the file will be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete a file in the repository but not in the filesystem, it means that you do not want to keep trace of this file. In Git you have 4 alternatives (as specified [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5363864/Git-4-Ways-to-Ignore-Files)).

1. You can use a .gitignore file. In this case the file/folder is locally untracked.
2. You can edit .git/info/exclude in a similar way as the previous case. Here the difference is that the file is locally untracked.
3. You can use the `git update-index assume-unchanged <filename>` command to track a file, but the local changes are ignored.
4. You can use `git update-index skip-worktree <filename>` command to track a file, but the local changes are ignored.

Points 3 and 4 appear to do the same thing, but there are difference. At this [link](https://fallengamer.livejournal.com/93321.html) you can find an extensive list of tests about the behavior of these points. To summarize the differences we can say that the flag `assume-unchanged` assumes that a developer does not touch a file anymore. The flag `skip-worktree` instructs git to not touch the specific file anymore. It is useful when you add to the repository a configuration file, but you do not want to track its changes.