# Accidentally committed dev database to Git

Tags: git

I accidentally committed my development.sqlite3 file to Git, and it seems to be slowing down my commits.  I know about .gitignore, but does this take the file out of my repository once I've done so?  My concern is is with reducing the commit and push times.

Comment: I believe you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesys

You need to add it to .gitignore, but also remove it from the repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/git-remove-file-accidentally-added-to-the-repository

Comment: quickfix: backup that file, create new with original name, add backup file to .gitignore and commit, than remove backup file from .gitignore and add there the db file, lastly restore the backup:)

Comment: @rjh: Uh, no. That's a very different question. That was about retroactively changing history. This is about .gitigore (among other things).

Comment: @bobDevil: This is not quite the same thing, as the commit's already been made, so it's `git rm --cached` and `git commit --amend`, not just `rm --cached`.

Comment: @T.E.D. Uh, no. This is also about changing history - the OP needs to fix the bad commit which has already been made. rjh's duplicate is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @Euwyn: For the record, though I provided an answer here as well, rjh's duplicate question is indeed a duplicate, and you'll likely find more detail there. Just remember to use `rm --cached` to avoid removing the copy in the work tree.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for fanciness with filter-branch - this is just in one recent commit. If not, simply remove the file (`git rm --cached <filename>`) and amend your commit (`git commit --amend`). The `--cached` option tells git to only remove the copy in the index (the commit staging area), and leave the version in the work tree intact.

If it's farther back in the history, you can use interactive rebase (`git rebase -i <commit before the bad one> master`), choose to `edit` the bad commit, and rm/amend as before. Be sure to add it to your gitignore as well, of course.

Note that if you've already pushed this commit, you'll have to use `push -f` to get the non-fast-forward to push, and if anyone else has pulled it already, they'll be annoyed (see the "recovering from upstream rebase" section in the man page of git-rebase.

Comment: I'm curious why this answer was downvoted - anyone care to tell me how it could be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  git filter-branch --tree-filter ´rm filename´ HEAD
```

Comment: `filter-branch` is definitely, definitely overkill. The file in question was only added in one commit and has not been modified since.

Answer (score -1):

No. All the .gitignore file does is tell the various Git user interface tools to ignore that file when batch-committing changes. You can still manually put any individual file you want into Git's database, and adding entires there will not remove anything from the Git revision database.

Comment: You haven't actually answered the real question, which is how to get rid of the file.