# Make git ignore files

Tags: git

I'm trying to make git ignore some of my files and I found one description about how you could do this

> From: http://github.com/guides/git-cheat-sheet
>   TO IGNORE SOME FILES
>
> Add a file in the root directory
>   called .gitignore and add some files
>   to it: (comments begin with hash)
>   *.log db/schema.rb db/schema.sql
>
> Git automatically ignores empty
>   directories. If you want to have a
>   log/ directory, but want to ignore all
>   the files in it, add the following
>   lines to the root .gitignore: (lines
>   beginning with ‘!’ are exceptions)
>
> log/* !.gitignore
>
> Then add an empty .gitignore in the
>   empty directory:
>
> touch log/.gitignore

So I made a file called .gitignore in my folder for my project and wrote the following in it:

```
phpMyAdmin/*
nbproject/*
inc/mysql_config.php
!.gitignore
```

But when I commit, the files isent excluded from the commit...

Comment: Are none of the files being excluded, or are some being excluded and others aren't? If you provide a little more detail about what're seeing and what you're expecting (including file paths) that would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Remove a file from the repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

Comment: Be carefull with that netbeans ignore... `nbproject should be checked into the version control system. nbproject contains project metadata that enables others users to open the project in NetBeans without having to import the project first.` [source](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/import-eclipse.html#versioning)

Comment: [https://www.gitignore.io/](https://www.gitignore.io/) I created a web utility that can help you generate useful .gitignore files for your project. It will help you ignore operating system, programming language, and IDE generated files.

Comment: That's really nice and useful!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [**man gitignore**](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that git should ignore. Note
>   that all the `gitignore` files really concern only files that are not already
>   tracked by git; in order to ignore uncommitted changes in already tracked files,
>   please refer to the [*git update-index --assume-unchanged*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) documentation.

So it doesn't help if you've already added them. It's mostly for preventing the addition in the first place. That way, you can ignore `.tmp` files and add a whole directory without worrying that you'll add the `.tmp` files.

I believe you can remove them from the index with:

```
git rm --cached file_to_stop_tracking_but_dont_want_to_delete.txt
```

**Update:**

Also, the `.gitignore` needs to be at the base directory or at least above where those directories are. Also, take the "*" out of the directories:

```
phpMyAdmin/
nbproject/
inc/mysql_config.php
!.gitignore
```

And be careful of `phpMyAdmin/` vs `/phpMyAdmin` vs `phpMyAdmin`. Also from [**man gitignore**](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> - If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the
>     following description, but it would only find a match with a directory.
>     In other words, `foo/` will match a directory `foo` and paths underneath
>     it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link `foo` (this is
>     consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in git).
> - If the pattern does not contain a slash `/`, git treats it as a shell
>     glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname without leading directories.
> - Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption
>     by [`fnmatch(3)`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fnmatch.html) with the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag: wildcards in the pattern
>     will not match a `/` in the pathname. For example, `Documentation/*.html`
>     matches `Documentation/git.html` but not `Documentation/ppc/ppc.html`. A
>     leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname; for example, `/*.c`
>     matches `cat-file.c` but not `mozilla-sha1/sha1.c`.

Comment: is the .gitignore in the same directory as these?

Comment: .gitignore is in the root of the project.

Comment: i had to include `-r` in order to remove the file(s) recursively, so git rm -r --cached path/to/file/