# git merge conflict with .class file

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I am new at git and I use windows for git (that's a lot of pain) , and now I'm having a merging trouble with conflict .class file. how should resolve this conflict? I don't really understand about this conflict.

Comment: 1. Read a git tutorial, for example http://gitimmersion.com/
2. Add *.class to .gitignore file. Compiled files should not be held in a repository.

Comment: yeah I know about it. I just forgot to ignore it at first. and now it making trouble. how should I overwrite it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Remove a file from the repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

Comment: It's obvious from reading the comments that your problem is that you've committed something you meant to ignore; there are a ton of questions about that. If you care, I put a list of other duplicates on this question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102408/why-is-git-not-ignoring-dcu-files#comment11433754_9102408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say don't even worry about resolving it. Just accept the merge, assuming the class file is the only conflict, using `git merge branch -Xtheirs`

This will merge as usual but accept all the changes from the branch you're merging from without checking for conflicts.

Alternately you can resolve the conflict manually if it makes you feel better.
From this point on there will be no more conflicts with .class files as you've added an entry to .gitignore.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to be executing this command? What if his merge has changes that actually need to be reviewed for conflicts?

Comment: Indeed, hence why I mentioned to only do this if that .class file is  the only conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Java, .class files are just generated machine-code from your compilation. It's not really source code, so there's no conflict resolution that needs to be done here. I would just overwrite the .class files in the target branch.

Comment: `git checkout --theirs <file>` or `git checkout --ours <file>` then `git add <file>`.

Answer (score 3):

I would not put class files that are generated from your sources into git at all.

You can still delete it locally and then `git rm <file>` it.