# How do I tell Git to ignore a specific filename only in the repository's top level?

Tags: git, gitignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to exclude file only from root folder in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637660/how-to-exclude-file-only-from-root-folder-in-git)

For a specific JavaScript project, I am using the [TinyWeb HTTP Server](http://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/) for local testing (to work around a specific security limitation that applies to file URLs). That program requires I have an `index.html` file in the root directory, but I do not want to commit that file to my Git repository.

How can I stop Git from bugging me about this "untracked file" on every commit? I do want to commit all `index.html` files located in subdirectories.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Add this to your `.gitignore` (in the root folder):

```
/index.html
```

The leading `/` makes git use an absolute path (relative to the current `.gitignore` location), whereas all other lines are just treated as some kind of wildcard.

Comment: But how do I do this in a global gitignore file? (core.excludesfile)?

Comment: @GregEnnis It works just the same there. The global ignore file, as well as the repository’s `.git/info/exclude` file are both interpreted in the same way as a `.gitignore` in the root of the working directory.

Comment: I have a /path/to/a/folder/.env and If I add that to the global ~/.gitignore, it does not ignore.

Comment: @ElijahLynn See [Why doesn't Git ignore my specified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833675/216074)

Comment: Ahh, I think this won't work, I am trying to ignore a file in a repo but in my top level ~/.gitignore, not the repo/.gitignore.

Comment: @ElijahLynn You mean the .gitignore is outside of the repository? That will only work when that file is configured explicitly as the excludefile with Git. But then it will also take repository-relative paths. Please open a new separate question if you can’t make it work.