# .gitignore exclude folder with files but include subdirectory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have folders like so:

```
/foo/one.txt
/foo/bar/two.txt
/foo/other/three.txt
```

I want to exclude everything in the folder /foo/ except the subfolder /foo/bar/. How do I do that?

With this .gitignore I've managed to exclude the "other" subfolder, but the file "one.txt" is still included.

```
/foo/*
!/foo/bar/
```

Comment: What you've done works as you wanted for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that while the `.gitignore` is now working you are suffering from the common problem of needing to remove a tracked file from the index that is now in gitignore e.g. [why-git-doesnt-ignore-my-specified-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833561/why-git-doesnt-ignore-my-specified-file/3834249#3834249)

That is, use `git rm <file>` to remove / make sure it is not in the index.

Comment: Thank you. It was in the index. Stupid of me to not actually check my own example :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Charles Bailey said in the comments section, your code works:

```
$ cat .gitignore 
/foo/*
!/foo/bar/

$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#   foo/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add foo/ -n
add 'foo/bar/two.txt'
$
```