# How do I remove a directory from a Git repository?

Tags: git, delete-file

How can I delete a single directory containing files from a Git repository?

Comment: You need only: `git rm -r --cached folder_name`

Comment: @Vadim I have found few more steps which needs to be done, depending on which step you have noticed you want to remove file. The command returned error when I have tried after I have added the folder to ```.gitignore```. It has returned ```fatal: pathspec 'venv/' did not match any files```. I had to take the folder out of ```.gitignore``` first, then ```git add <folder>```,  then run ```it rm -r --cached <folder>``` and then add it back to ```.gitignore```. It took me a some time to find out why it did not work at first place.

Answer (score 3097, accepted):

##### Remove directory from Git and local

Checkout 'master' with both directories:

```
git rm -r one-of-the-directories // This deletes from filesystem
git commit . -m "Remove duplicated directory"
git push origin <your-git-branch> (typically 'master', but not always)
```

##### Remove directory from Git but NOT local

To remove this directory from Git, but not delete it entirely from the filesystem (local):

```
git rm -r --cached myFolder
```

Comment: I had same exact situation. When I tried `git rm -r myFolder` it worked, but also deleted everything from "MyFolder" directory.  Had to revert everything in the "MyFolder" directory and then commit.

Comment: @Justin To only remove from git and leave filesystem as-is, use `git rm -r --cached myFolder`

Comment: figured it out, click the trashcan

Comment: Be aware that if you are working on a shared repo by others, despite you run the "--cached" version, they will get that folder removed from their local copy at the moment they pull new changes. Refer to this explanation about that https://gist.github.com/scy/6636390

Comment: And use `git rm -r --cached *` to delete everything

Comment: how can chose from witch branch?

Comment: `git rm -r --cached myFolder` will stage the removal on the current branch which then still needs to be committed & pushed

Comment: @karmakaze fatal: pathspec 'myFolder' did not match any files.But I can see 'myFolder' in repo with 'git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD' command.

Comment: Error message I get is:
fatal: pathspec 'directory' did not match any files.

Comment: @user2441441 I had this error poping up when I was trying to remove a folder/file that was not added to the repo at all

Comment: @lukeatdesignworks I had the same error. Apparently removing all files from the directory removed the directory itself from version control, so trying to remove that directory gave the "fatal: pathspec 'directory' did not match any files" error.

Comment: .gitignore has no effect when I add exclusions after running `git rm -r --cached to_be_excluded_dir`. Everything is added again.

Comment: `git rm -r --cached directory/`only removes from git tracked, but the repository structure remains.

Comment: `fatal: pathspec 'web/assets/2d40d8f2/' did not match any files` will be thrown when you use the `git rm --cached web/assets/2d40d8f2/`

Comment: What does the `.` signifiy in `git commit . -m "Remove duplicated directory"`?

Comment: `.` (aka dot/period) signifies the current directory. I believe it works on all platforms (but I'm less certain of Windows versions).

Comment: @lukeatdesignworks You would get this error if the directory is empty as well. Because, by default git ignores empty directories.

Answer (score 468):

#### To remove folder/directory only from git repository and not from the local try 3 simple commands.

---

**Steps to remove directory**

```
git rm -r --cached FolderName
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository"
git push origin master
```

---

**Steps to ignore that folder in next commits**

> To ignore that folder from next commits make one file in root folder (main project directory where the git is initialized) named **.gitignore**
> and put that folder name into it. You can ignore as many files/folders as you want

**.gitignore** file will look like this

```
/FolderName
```

---

[image: remove directory]

Comment: You will also need to do the git rm -r --cached FolderName
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository" on your other computer and then do a pull to keep it in synch.

Comment: Will this delete the directory from the point it was added to repository till now? Or is it just to remove the directory and recommit it to the .git repo?

Comment: Why not just do a `rm -rf FolderName; git add -A; git commit -m 'removed FolderName` ?

Comment: well done. On my machine, the third step doesnt work. But it works if it is changed to $git push

Comment: Unlucky for me: robdavisprojects@Robs-MacBook-Air default % ls
default.services.yml drushrc.php  settings.ddev.php
default.settings.php files   settings.php
robdavisprojects@Robs-MacBook-Air default % git rm -r --cached files
fatal: pathspec 'files' did not match any files
robdavisprojects@Robs-MacBook-Air default %

Comment: Answer for me: folder "files" was not controlled by git, so that's all good. I can just rmdir files or rm -Rf files

Answer (score 90):

If, for some reason, what karmakaze said doesn't work, you could try deleting the directory you want using or with your file system browser (ex. In Windows File Explorer). After deleting the directory, issuing the command: 
`git add -A` 
and then 
`git commit -m 'deleting directory'` 
and then 
`git push origin master`.

Comment: This worked for me. Could you explain the -A argument ?

Comment: @Arun -A is short for --all and add changes from all tracked and untracked files

Comment: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Answer (score 35):

I already had committed the folder before and want to remove the directory in the history as well.

I did the following:

Add folder to `.gitignore`:

```
echo Folder_Name/ >> .gitignore
```

Remove from all commits:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch Folder_Name/' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

remove the refs from the old commits:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

Ensure all old refs are fully removed

```
rm -Rf .git/logs .git/refs/original
```

Perform a garbage collection

```
git gc --prune=all --aggressive
```

push you changes to the online repository:

```
git push
```

You are done here.

But you can to the following to push all the changes to all branches with:
But be careful with this command!

```
git push origin --all --force
git push origin --tags --force
```

After that the folder was removed from git, but was not deleted from local disk.

Comment: This does not work on Windows. XARGS not recognized.

Answer (score 31):

You can try this:
**`git rm -rf <directory_name>`**

It will force delete the directory.

Comment: this will also delete from local directory

Answer (score 21):

If you remove the files in the directory (with `git rm` as the other answers explain), then the directory no longer exists as far as git is concerned. You cannot commit an empty directory, nor can you remove one.

This is unlike subversion where you have to explicitly `svn rm emptyfolder/`, and is incidentally why the `man` page for git describes itself as "the stupid content tracker"

An answer on ["How do I add an empty directory to a git repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) links to the [FAQ on this subject](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F):

> Currently the design of the git index
>   (staging area) only permits files to
>   be listed, and nobody competent enough
>   to make the change to allow empty
>   directories has cared enough about
>   this situation to remedy it.
>
> Directories are added automatically
>   when adding files inside them. That
>   is, directories never have to be added
>   to the repository, and are not tracked
>   on their own.
>
> You can say "`git add <dir>`" and it
>   will add files in there.
>
> If you really need a directory to
>   exist in checkouts you should create a
>   file in it. .gitignore works well for
>   this purpose; you can leave it empty,
>   or fill in the names of files you
>   expect to show up in the directory.

Answer (score 11):

for **deleting Empty folders**

i wanted to delete an empty directory(folder) i created, git can not delete it, after some research i learned
Git doesn't track empty directories. If you have an empty directory in your working tree you should simply removed it with

```
rm -r folderName
```

There is no need to involve Git.

Answer (score 9):

Go to your git Directory then type the following command:
**rm -rf <*Directory Name*>**

After Deleting the directory commit the changes by:
**git commit -m "Your Commit Message"**

Then Simply push the changes on remote GIT directory:
**git push origin <*Branch name*>**

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the folder locally and then push, as follow:

```
git rm -r folder_name
git commit -m "your commit"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually use `git add --all` to remove files / folders from remote repositories

```
rm -r folder_name
git add --all
git commit -m "some comment"
git push origin master
```

`master` can be replaced by any other branch of the repository.

Answer (score 5):

A combination of the 2 answers worked for me

```
git rm -r one-of-the-directories
git commit . -m "Remove duplicated directory"
git push
```

if it still shows some warning, remove the files manually

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD
git push
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Attlasian Source Tree (Windows) (https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview). 
Just select files from tree and push button "Remove" at the top. Files will be deleted from local repository and local git database. Then Commit, then push.

Answer (score 2):

One of my colleague suggested [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which I think powerful. It is not only delete unwanted data but also clean your repository from any related commit information.

Answer (score 2):

First git command need to know who you are before deleting anything

1. git init
2. git config user.name "someone"
3. git config user.email "someone@someplace.com"
4. git rm -r
5. git commit -m "deleting dir"
6. git push origin master

Answer (score 2):

To add new directory:

```
mkdir <YOUR-DIRECTORY>
```

But now Git is not aware by this new directory, because Git keep tracks of file not directories
DIRECTORY

```
git status
```

Git won't be aware with the change we've made, so we add hidden `.keep` file to make Git aware by this new change.

```
touch /YOUR-directory/.keep
```

Now, if you hit `git status` Git will be aware with the changes.

And If you want to delete the directory, you should use this command.

```
rm -r <YOUR-DIRECTORY>
```

And If you checked by using `git status`, you will see the directory has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deleting directory from GitHub web application, you will find a delete option. However, after that it will give you list of files being deleted, with commit option at the bottom. Do remember to commit it. Otherwise, directory will not be deleted.

Reference - https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/deleting-files-in-a-repository