# How to delete one folder from git repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a folder called "Serverside Project" that I want to delete from my git repo online. I can't seem to be able to get rid of it! How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: You cannot push a commit that deletes it?

Answer (score 47):

You can just delete the folder locally and then push, ex:
`rm -rf folder`
`git add .`
`git commit -a -m "removed folder"`
`git push origin master`

Comment: The problem is I have deleted the folder on my local drive which is at another location but the folder is still in my online repo, so I want to delete the folder 'Serverside Project' from my online repo then pull all the other folders and files that are on my online repo atm.

Comment: Oh I see, then why don't you clone the repo delete the folder then push?

Comment: @MauricioTrajano you can do it faster using `git rm -r folder`

Comment: I tried doing that and this is what I got:
`$ git rm -r Serverside Project`
`fatal: pathspec 'Serverside' did not match any files`

Comment: Spaces are treated as separate arguments do `git rm -r Serverside\ Project`

Comment: These steps were a life saver for me! Thank you!

Comment: @Chris Maes - thanks. yes and my repo was still in the local cache - was able to remove it via https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927283 - it then removed it from the server after push