# remove directory from gitlab after initial commit

Tags: git

I added my project to gitlab with an inital commit. I realize now I dont need to tack such folders as node_modules, build, dist so I added them to a `gitignore` file. The issue is they are in the gitlab online directory still. Can I just delete them right from the application? Or will this mess anything up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove directory from remote repository after adding them to .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore)

Comment: @alexander.polomodov yep that answered it. Should I remove this question or just leave it?

Comment: It will be closed as duplicate later. Do not worry about it

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git rm --cached <folder>/*
```

In order to remove those folders from git but leave it in the local folder.