# git pull deletes files to be ignored

Tags: git

I had a broken .gitignore file in my repository so other files also got commited.

According to the post below I removed those unnecessary files and my repo looks clean however since then every time I do a git pull those files (meant to be ignored) get physically deleted from the directory.

[Remove directory from remote repository after adding them to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore)

I worked out a fix:

- copy the old tree
- remove .git
- git init
- git remote add a_new_repository
- make a change just for the sake of a commit
- git add .
- git commit
- git push

However this way I lose previous commits.

Is there a less painful way?

Thanks

**EDIT**

So the command I used were:

- git rm -r --cached some-directory
- git commit -m 'Remove the now ignored directory "some-directory"'
- git push origin master

Then after git pull I get a long list of removed files

> ...
>
> delete mode 100644 themes/stark/README.txt
>   delete mode 100644 themes/stark/layout.css
>   delete mode 100644 themes/stark/logo.png 
>   delete mode 100644 themes/stark/screenshot.png
>   delete mode 100644 themes/stark/stark.info
>   delete mode 100644 update.php
>   delete mode 100644 web.config
>   delete mode 100644 xmlrpc.php

Comment: Please post a complete log of what commands you entered and what the output was.

Comment: You are not providing enough information to ascertain the cause of your issues. We need to see a reproducible issue that you are having, not just errors.