# laravel gitIgnore doesn't ignore my folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like to ignore whole 'public' folder, I added this manually to my gitIgnore file, but still when I commit I can see things from this folder. How to do to file gitignore start ignore this?

My gitignore looks like this:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
.env
composer.lock
/public
/.idea
.phpstorm.meta.php
_ide_helper.php
npm-debug.log
package-lock.json
.gitattributes
```

Comment: `git rm -r /public --cached`?

Comment: I don't want to remove this folder, I want to stop adding this all the time when I do commit

Comment: That is wat the `--cached` option is for

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do it:

1. temporarily move out from repository the public folder.
2. Do commit
3. move it back. It will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You can use -

```
git rm -r --cached <your file/directory Name>
```

Comment: directories also need `-r` for recursive