# How to specify paths in .gitignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application, using git for synchronising code between stakeholders. The application has the ability to send emails. Each stakeholder has his own SMTP provider which is defined in `config/initializers/smtp.rb` during installation.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.emailme.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "emailme.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "me@emailme.com",
    password: "Password"
    }
```

The .gitignore file is defined as:

```
*.rbc
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/log
/tmp
/public/system
/coverage/
/spec/tmp
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html

## Environment normalization:
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle

# these should all be checked in to normalize the environment:
# Gemfile.lock, .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset
Gemfile~

config/initializers/smtp.rb
```

.gitignore files are identical on Github and on my computer. I tried to specify

> config/initializers/smtp.rb

or

> /config/initializers/smtp.rb

But whatever, the `smtp.rb` file on my computer gets overwritten with the file on Github. And it's the same the other way round.
What did I miss?

Comment: If you want to ignore this file, why does it exist on your GitHub repo?

Comment: You could remove the file from remote first:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32182171/3450689

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @oliver, the file should not exist on git. You can remove the file from git by doing

```
git rm --cached config/initializers/smtp.rb
git commit -m "Removed config file from repo"
git push
```

Please do note `--cached`, it is very important otherwise you can lose the file from you local directory. This option will remove the file only from repo.

See: [Remove directory from remote repository after adding them to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore/32182171#32182171) if you want to Add directory to `.gitignore`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**.gitignore** will tell git to ignore changes to files that are not currently being tracked by git.

Run `git rm --cached config/initializers/smtp.rb` to stop git from tracking future changes to the file.

Create a `config/initializers/smtp.template.rb` with dummy values, and commit + push your changes.

Direct any new stakeholders to run `cp config/initializers/smtp.template.rb config/initializers/smtp.rb` and update the file when setting up their development environment.