# How to remove cached/tracked files after adding a gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder in my repository called `Design`. I have since added `/Design/` to my `.gitignore` file. However, the old files are still tracked and appear in bitbucket. How can I remove these cached files from my online repository but keep them on my computer? I tried something in the past but ended up deleting them from my computer, and I don't want that to happen again!

Comment: Rename the folder. (Back it up somewhere temporarily, if you like.) `git rm Design`. Rename it back.

Comment: @ceejayoz When I did that it said `fatal: not removing 'Design' recursively without -r`

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear. Add the `-r`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gitignore after commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535362/gitignore-after-commit)

Comment: @ceejayoz Yep worked, thanks, if you put that as an answer I'll accept. I was just cautious because I've tried a few answers on here and bad things happened haha.

Comment: @ceejayoz There's the `--cached` flag, which removes the file from the index while keeping it in the working tree, i.e. `git rm --cached -r Design`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove directory from remote repository after adding them to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+after+add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just mean to remove the files from the repo going forward, the simplest way is

```
git rm --cached -r Design
```

to update the index, and then when you commit the new commit will omit the directory.

Backing the files up, then doing

```
git rm -r Design
```

and then copying the files back (per comments) also works, but is unnecessarily complicated since that's exactly what the `--cached` option is for.

If you mean to purge the `Design` folder from the repo entirely, this is more involved and requires a history rewrite (which in turn has some costs you would need to read up about).  You can find plenty of questions and answers that outline all of this; you'd be looking for `git filter-branch` info