# cannot add folder to gitignore file

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` file is the following:

```
$ cat .gitignore
Index/
Index/LOG
```

I added `.gitignore` file to repo, commit and even push. But `git status` permanently shows:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Index/LOG
#
```

So how to exclude whole `Index` folder from git repository forever?

Comment: if `Index/LOG` was added, you should delete it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git doesn't ignore tracked files.  You need to delete that file from the repository before it will be ignored:

```
$ git rm -r Index
$ git commit -m "Deleting 'Index' folder."
```

This will remove the files. If you only want to remove them from the index use `--cached`:

```
$ git rm -r --cached Index
```

This will keep all files in the file-system and only removes them from git.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the the `Index` folder, remove it and commit the changes. This is outlined in:

- [How to remove a directory in my GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6313126/367456)

That simple it is. If you only want to update the index telling git that nothing changed even it changed, use the `update-index` commmand:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366713/367456