# Delete deleted files/folder when updating a git repo

Tags: git, github

I created a git repo and commited files/folder, after some time a deleted a folder from my local git folder and in try to update the repo I run the commands -

```
git add .
git commit -m "second commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/trialcode/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

But the removed folder is still shown there in my git repo although the files were updated. Let me know what I am doing wrong with the git files/folder update.

**FYI** - I tried `git branch -d folder_to_remove/`
but it is throwing an error - `error: branch 'folder_to_remove/' not found`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to remove a directory in my GitHub repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git will have a hidden folder `.git/` in your local repo directory. Everything about your local repository will be stored inside that folder.

So When You create a folder and commit, it will be stored.After that even if you delete the file or folder from your file system it will not be notified to local git repository.

To notify git that you have deleted a file or folder use the command `git rm`.

Try this

```
git rm folder_name
git commit -m "removed folder"
git remote add origin https://github.com/trialcode/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

Here `folder_name` is the filename or folder name which you wish to remove.

Comment: +1 and as a note - we need to add `-r` flag to remove the directories recursively.

Answer (score 13):

[Vijay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24772378/456814) will work, but I also want to point out an additional solution.

Normally `git add` won't add deleted files to your staging area (to be committed), so when you ran

```
git add .
```

you didn't actually stage any of your deleted files.

### Staging deleted files with `git add`

If you want `git add` to actually stage deleted files, then you have to use the `--update` or -`u` flags:

```
git add --update
# Or
git add -u
```

Additionally, you can also use the `--all` or `-A` flag, but if I remember correctly, that flag only stages deleted files starting with Git version 2.0...or something like that. Note also that the flag will also stage untracked files, unlike `-u`, which only updates already-tracked files:

```
git add --all
# Or
git add -A
```

### Documentation

- [git-add(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

Comment: Thx for the additional info +1