# Push data from git to github. file too big but can't file the file in repository

Tags: git, github, push

[Error when I push to github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cbd3.jpg)

I'm trying to push my code in Github but I have a problem. It says that there is file greater than 100mo and can't upload it. However, I removed this file and folder from my local repo.

It says the folder import has a file too big. However, this folder does not exist anymore in my repo.

Anyone knows how I can remove a folder in git that I can't see anymore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository

Comment: @marxan, please include your image into question, do not post on external resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#_removing_files_that_have_disappeared_from_the_filesystem) put it, the easiest way to remove a file from a local repository is by deleting the file from the disk, and then recording the removal:

```
git status
git add filename
git commit -m "removed filename"
```

Also related [Delete deleted files/folder when updating a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772042/delete-deleted-files-folder-when-updating-a-git-repo).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that folder is not on the disk anymore but seems to be still in my local repo

Comment: then just record the change, i.e. the removal of the file, by adding and commiting it. this change should be visible when you do `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

The file is likely still referenced from some of the previous commits.

You should run `git filter-branch` - see https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/#using-filter-branch.

This is a possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)