# How to remove a renamed folder from github

Tags: git, github

I had a folder on github, say `folder` which I renamed to `folder1` a few commits ago. I now see that both `folder` and `folder1` show up in my repository. How can I remove the old folder. I have tried git rm and git mv but they don't work because `folder` doesn't exist in my directory tree anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `git mv` to rename folders:

```
git mv <old> <new>
```

It will rename your folder, remove the old name from your repository, and add the new one. You also can use this bunch of commands:

```
mv <old> <new>
git add <new>
git rm <old>
```

If you want to remove a whole directory that has already been pushed, use this:

```
git rm -r <old>
git commit -m "Remove unused directory"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: git rm -rf directory_name

It will force delete the directory.