# Delete a folder from Github

Tags: git, github

New to Github.I am in the development branch not the master branch and i have pushed a folder few days and
now i want to delete that folder.Tried `git rm -r FolderName`and `git rm -rf FolderName` 
but it is saying `fatal: pathspec 'FolderName' didn't match any files`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't store specific information about folders, only about files. A folder is automatically removed if it is empty (empty means if also doesn't contain ignored files!). So just remove all files inside it and done. In your case, it seems you already removed all files (after `git rm -r FolderName`, this is the case). Whenever you do a `git checkout` from a commit which contains to folder to one which doesn't, your folder should disappear automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am unable to remove the folder as it is giving an error fatal:pathspec 'FolderName' didnt match any files.its is still on github.com

Comment: How does `git status` list it? Maybe you just forgot to do `git push` to push the changes to github?

Comment: Your idea of removing the individual files from the folder has worked. Thanks a lot.