# Git does not delete folders after merge

Tags: git

Suppose I have a repository with branches A and B, stemming from the same origin. I switch to the A branch and delete some directories. Those directories contain some files. Then I do commit and switch to the branch B, where those directories are not deleted yet. So, I merge B with A but I don't see folders being removed in branch B. Rather I have weird situations with half-deleted folders and self-restoring folders. So, how do I correctly commit and merge deletions into the main development branch?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about what you mean here *Then I do commit and pull another branch B*?

Comment: @TimCastelijns well, basically I just switch to the branch B. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Git doesn't track directories. For example, Git only cares about a directory `foo` if it is necessary for a tracked file such as `foo/bar.txt`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a directory in my GitHub repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository)

Comment: @chepner Or if it contains a `.gitkeep` file (not actually a Git feature, just a convention thing if you wanted to track folders).

Comment: well, those folders are not empty, of course. But when I do commit and switch back to the A branch, the folders and their nested folders are restored. The files are gone, but directories are there.

Comment: Git is treating the directories like any other untracked file; it doesn't delete them when changing branches.