# Error: Cannot find module './drivers' with mongoose only on the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoose works fine on the computer

but on the server I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './drivers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pmx/lib/transaction.js:59:21)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/WTV.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OK!** I took me a while but I found the solution

1. **in commandline write:** heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false --app
2. make some change and push the project
3. **in commandline write:** heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true --app

**Good luck :)**

Comment: What if we don't use heroku and still get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue. I am using the MEAN stack with mongoose as my ODM and hosting on Heroku:

```
Error: Cannot find module './drivers'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:5:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
```

In addition to setting `NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` as stated [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support) (under section Cache Behavior), I had to remove my `node_modules` directory from the git repo (also recommended in the Heroku docs). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository) on how to remove a directory from git.

Also, adding "node_modules" directory to your .gitignore file is a good idea. NOTE: This does not remove the files from git, you still have to remove any previously committed files or directories that you want ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I simply ran `heroku run bash` in the cloned directory and typed in `rm -rf node_modules` and ran `npm install` from there. Simply ran the server through `heroku run bash` and worked fine! Hopefully this will work for you. Ensure to have `node_modules` in your `.gitignore` file.