# How to remove a folder from Github repository?

Tags: git

I followed the steps given as answer to the following question: [How to remove a directory from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository)

However when I execute (last command out of 3)

> git push origin master

I get the following error (which I couldn't resolve even when trying to push files/folders without --force):

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dragGH102/leaderboard-meteor.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried with

> git pull origin master

but it opens a CLI Interface on which I don't know how to interact (I'm on Linux).

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT _ full shell content:**

```
git rm -r .meteor
> git commit -m "Remove extra directory"

[master e901990] Remove extra directory
 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
> git push origin master

Username for 'https://github.com': dragGH102
Password for 'https://dragGH102@github.com': 
To https://github.com/dragGH102/leaderboard-meteor.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dragGH102/leaderboard-meteor.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

> git pull origin master

# open GUI (no idea how to interact here and what to do)
Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/dragGH102/leaderboard-meteor

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
                              [ line 1/8 (12%), col 1/73 (1%), char 0/300 (0%) ]
^G Get Help       ^O WriteOut       ^R Read File      ^Y Prev Page      ^K Cut Text       ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit           ^J Justify        ^W Where Is       ^V Next Page      ^U UnCut Text     ^T To Spell
```

Comment: can you post the CLI interface that appears when you pull? one test is to create another branch on remote (maybe you are having permission issues)

Comment: I just edited my answer with full shell + GUI

Comment: Just save the merge commit and you are fine. After merging you are able to push your stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull` includes merging and that’s exactly what you are facing. If there was no change in upstream, there would be a **fast-forward merge**.

> Often the current branch head is an ancestor of the named commit. This
>   is the most common case especially when invoked from `git pull`: you are
>   tracking an upstream repository, you have committed no local changes,
>   and now you want to update to a newer upstream revision. In this case,
>   a new commit is not needed to store the combined history; instead, the
>   HEAD (along with the index) is updated to point at the named commit,
>   without creating an extra merge commit.

However, as both your repo and upstream has changed, you’re facing a **true merge**.

> A merged version reconciling the changes from all branches to be
>   merged is committed, and your HEAD, index, and working tree are
>   updated to it. It is possible to have modifications in the working
>   tree as long as they do not overlap; the update will preserve them.

Since there are no conflicts, you can finish the merge by just typing the commit message.

Source of quotes: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

More info: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 2):

This will remove directory from git and local

```
git rm -r the_directory
git commit -m "Remove duplicated directory"
git push origin master
```

To remove only from git

```
git rm -r --cached folder_name
```

Comment: it's exactly what I did (following the answer mentioned). BUt I get that error