# Remove git repo

Tags: git

Accidentally I've created some files in `/dev/projectname/projectname`

I've initiated git repo `git remote add origin git@bitbucket...`

then i did this from `/dev`:

```
mv projectname projectname_d
mv projectname_d/projectname projectname
rm -rf projectname_d
```

Then i've found out, that repo is located in `/dev` somehow, so if i run `git status` it lists all folders in `/dev`

How do i fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a directory in my GitHub repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rm -r .git` from the repo root

Answer (score 2):

All the information about that git repository are stored in the .git subdirectory of your project.

If you want to completely un-version a directory you should remove that subdirectory with

```
rm -rf .git
```

Running `git status` you'll see that that directory is "Not a git repository"