# Xcode Remove unit tests from Github

Tags: xcode, github

I'm tying to remove **unit tests** from **Github** in Xcode .

I removed unit tests and commit and push but the unit tests folder in Github still there , Now i know that unit tests is important but it's college project and i don't want the professors to ask about it .

So how to remove it from Github ? , And if you know any great tutorials about **Unit Tests** i'll be thankful .

### Update:

When i remove the **unit tests** from target automatically Xcode removed the unit tests folders but when i close my project and reopened the unit tests folder was still there but not in the target so i simply remove the folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a directory from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-from-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll need to remove corresponded folders from your project directory, and then commit-push all changes using the following commands:

  - `git add .`
  - `git commit -m "YOUR_MESSAGE"`
  - `git push`
- Lynda tutorial series is a great way to achieve different skills in iOS development. Check the following link: [Lynda TDD](https://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/iOS-App-Development-Test-Driven-Development/672254-2.html)

Comment: thank you i remove it from target and forgot the folder .