# How to push changes to Github after deleting a folder

Tags: git, github

I have 3 files, and one of them is a .idea file. I accidentally pushed this file to Github, and now I want to delete it, so I did `git rm -r --cached .idea` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-from-git-repository) to remove it from git, but when I try to push the changes, it says

```
Everything up-to-date
```

How do I push the changes to Github?

Comment: Did you `commit` the changes after `rm` and before `push`?

Comment: I assume the remove command didnt worked for you. Can you try `git rm -rf your_dir_name`

Comment: @GinoMempin When I tried to commit it, it says "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: @KunalVohra Yes, now I can commit the changes, thank you!

Comment: Perfect, I post the same in answer for other community users. :) @F.M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the remove command didn't worked for you. Can you try `git rm -rf your_dir_name`