# How do you delete a folder with files in it in Git Bash?

Tags: command-line, git-bash

What command do I use to delete a folder and all contents in it using Git Bash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a directory from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-from-git-repository)

Comment: @martian111, no, because "git bash" is just the copy of bash compiled for windows shipped with git; this isn't really a question about git at all, just a question about UNIX shells.

Comment: That said, it's off-topic here, as it's not about programming; such questions belong at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/), whereas Stack Overflow is specific to questions _about writing code_.

Comment: (unless it _is_ about git itself instead of about git-bash, in which case it should be tagged differently)

Answer (score 6):

the other answers are correct if you are talking about Git, but if you're talking about just deleting a folder in a Bash terminal (like the one installed with Git SCM), then you could do it this way:

```sh
rm -rf folderName
```

The `r` option is for "recursive".

the `f` option is for "force" (so that it removes a folder even if it has files in it).

Here's a [manual page](https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html) that outlines how to use the `rm` command in Bash.

Comment: Please don't answer obviously off-topic questions. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and its link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This post answers my question. I was specifically asking how to remove a folder with files in it in Git Bash. I apologize for asking an off-topic question. Going forward, I'll make sure to post any future questions within the proper area(s).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, This is not an *obviously* off-topic question, at least not for everyone. I can't be the only one out there who wasn't really aware that Git, Git bash are separated things. Gosh, even the difference between programming and scripting is sometimes unclear to me. Everyone has been a beginner at some point, I think it's a good idea to keep that in mind when addressing others here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git rm -r --cached <folder>
git commit -m "Removed Folder"
git push origin master
```

Comment: @Jermal, if this is the answer you wanted, your question should have been tagged `git`, not `git-bash`. (git-bash is just a copy of bash compiled for Windows using msys2 libraries; the only thing it has to do with git is that it's distributed as part of the same installer package on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

git push origin master
git commit -m "Remove duplicated directory"
git push origin master

Comment: git rm -r folder-name
git commit -m "Remove duplicated directory"
git push origin master