# Gitlab folder structure not updating after push

Tags: git, directory, gitlab, structure

Inside my React project I've renamed the folder from "Components" to "components" and worked fine locally to solve an import/export issue. After I've pushed it to Gitlab it shows two folders "components" and "Components".

I downloaded the repository and it contains only one folder, which is correct, but when I send it to remote I am unable to solve this issue.

I've tried upload it to Github and also on Github it shows both folders. Anyone has a sugestion on how to fix or what may be the cause?

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-from-git-repository)? Specifically have you tried `git rm -r --cached Components`

Comment: I haven't seen it before! Thanks, it really helped me solve this issue.