# Remove folder from git repository/history

Tags: github, version-control, git-bash, large-files, git-lfs

I accidentally commited/pushed large folders to github and am unable to push further. When trying to commit and push I receive the following message. "batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access." I would like to remove the .next **folder**. and I do not want to purchase more storage. I am using git bash and windows 10.

Attempts I have tried so far.

1. Adding to `.gitignore` file and pushing.
2. Following the example and solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

   *git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf .next" --prune-empty HEAD
   git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
   echo .next/ >> .gitignore
   git add .gitignore
   git commit -m 'Removing .next from git history'
   git gc
   git push origin master --force*
3. The solution provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-from-git-repository)

   *git rm -r --cached myFolder*
4. The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository)

*CD to your local working folder and run the following command:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FOLDERNAME" -- --all
replace FOLDERNAME with the file or folder you wish to remove from the given git repository.
Once this is done run the following commands to clean up the local repository:
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
Now push all the changes to the remote repository:
git push --all --force
```

This will clean up the remote repository.*

My repository is linked below.

https://github.com/Rinzler8806/crowdCoin

I appreciate your help!