# GIT : How do I ignore a directory that is already in the repository without deleting or moving it?

Tags: git

Initially I wanted a directory and its contents to be managed in my project.
Now I'd prefer it was ignored entirely.  I also want to continue working in it, so I don't want to move it or delete it.  How do I accomplish this?

edit:

I forgot to mention that I do have a .gitignore file and that I did try to add it, but that doesn't seem to stop git from noticing modifications to files that were present in previous commits.

Maybe I'm not using the right pattern.
Assuming the directory is called test, in the root, I've tried the following:
test/
test/*
test*

Comment: In the future you should make sure you are clear about what technology you are asking about (git in this case) in the title and description. People won't always look at the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Remove a file from the repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to remove the folder from the index.

`git rm -r --cached test/`

Then, add to `.gitignore` the test directory with just `test/*` assuming it is in the root.

Commit git ignore

`git add .gitignore`

`git commit -m "added test directory"`

Check to see if it worked with `git status`

And that should be it :)

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. I've run into similar things with Git before. It can be a little goofy.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .gitignore file in the top level of your working directory. Add a line with the name of the directory you want ignored. Don't forget to add and commit your .gitignore!

See here for more info:
http://book.git-scm.com/4_ignoring_files.html

Comment: That's the first thing I tried.  I suppose I'm asking, exactly what should the pattern be because none seem to work.  See edit above.