# git remove file from repository but leave it on file system

Tags: git

I try to remove unnecessary files from git repository. That files were initially added and now they are in several branches. What I want is simply stop tracking changes in that files, I don't care what changes should stay there, but I need that files to stay on file system.

I tried following

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file_to_remove" HEAD
```

but that removed file from file system what is unwanted.

Comment: I usually copy the files somewhere before running that command. After git deletes them, I add them to .gitignore and then move the copies back.

Comment: Hmm, nice hack. I have not thought about it

Comment: @misha Do you want to stop tracking them, or completely remove them from the repository?   You say one thing in your question and another in a comment.

Comment: @andy, May be I wrongly say repository. I want to make the situation like `git add` for that files was never called for that files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just:

```
git rm --cached file [file ...]
```

Of course you'll need to make sure the offending files are added to your `.gitignore` so they don't get recommitted straight away

Comment: I want to remove them completely from repository from all branches. When I do as you say, file is stopped being tracked, but I can't switch branch, git says `File level merge required. Stay on branch <branch_name>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the file in the repository, you can use: 
`git update-index --assume-unchanged <fileName>`

This keeps the current version of the file in the index, but you can change it all you want and git will ignore those changes.

Comment: I have found that his approach is good only as a **temporary** workaround.  You will be prevented from checking out another branch in which the contents of the file are different from that of the current branch.

Answer (score -5):

Checkout and run **git clean** for each branch.

> git-clean - Remove untracked files from the working tree
>
> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean