# How to remove a file from git repository without deleting the file actually

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git: Remove a file from the repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

I know that the code "git rm" can remove a file from git repository,but it also delete the file from muy computer.

Is there a method to remove a file from git repository without deleting the file from my computer actually?

Comment: yes,I see.Thanks to you all~~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git rm --cached filename`

will keep the file on your computer.

It's the git equivalent to svn's `svn delete --keep-local`