# How work on Android Studio Project with more people

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am currently working with my friend on a android app project using android studio.

We are working separately on our PC's.

**Can you suggest a way do that we can sync our projects on Github?**

We tried to use the inbuit github feature of android studio but it resulted in nothing.

Comment: You are trying to see his coding live? Or just work on the same code, but sometimes in different hours, sometime in the same hour, etc?

Comment: We are both working separately on our own laptops.

Comment: You can always use [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) from the android studio working directory

Comment: Possible Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295943/how-to-use-git-correctly-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297246/3117650) answer I think you only need to understand how to use Git

[GitHub With Android Studio](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/)

[Github - Using Android Studio](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Android-Studio)

Comment: Thanks for the answer .

Comment: @ujjwalgupta if works for you better than say thanks is Tick with the right icon. But I'm happy that I could help

Comment: okk . Actually i am new to stack overflow, so i am still in the learning phase.