# How can I share an Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, file, share

I'm currently working on a project with another person, aat first we tried using the Google Drive desktop App but due to the App adding .ini files the project won´t work. So now we tried exporting but even then it doesn´t really works, so I wanna know how can we share the file. I´m also new in this kinda stuff.

Comment: My company uses [WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com)

Comment: See: [How to use Git correctly in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34295943/295004)

Comment: working with two or more person on same project will become much easier and efficient if you use `git` and `github`. it might take some time to understand its basics but it will help you big time for the **rest of your life**

Comment: To be clear [github](https://github.com/pricing) is a git cloud service and there are [other](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing) [vendors](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) with a free tier, but otherwise agree with @ganjaam about learning source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title doesn't match your question. You don't want to share your project, you want to work on it with multiple people at the same time.

The industry standard solution for this is using a version control software called **git**. Git allows you to easily create different revisions of your project and jump back and forth between those. This is done by grouping code changes to a **commit**. A commit kind of creates a snapshot of the current state of your project which you can always jump back to. For example if something breaks.

You can also host your project on a git server: This allows multiple people to **clone** the same project, make changes to it on separate **branches**, **push** the code back to the server and **merge** the changes.

The most popular solutions are [github](https://github.com/) and probably [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) which both offer free tiers.