# Why do pycharm add .xml files to git automatically?

Tags: xml, git, github, pycharm

I try to learn [pycharm] as programming tool using it on both Mac and Windows. PyCharm seems to add several .[xml] files and directories to [git] automatically. As I must be doing something wrong I am very aware about avoiding accepting the tracking of those files, but they  [seem to be added by "themselves"](https://github.com/hrasmussendk/icloud2lr_photoimport/tree/master).

I managed to do [a git reset file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124053/accidentally-committed-idea-directory-files-into-git) and a git rm -r --cached ./* and i've also added a .gitignore to avoid future commits of the unwanted files, but often they arrive in the project directory (by PyCharm) without knowing it so I can't add them to .gitignore in advance.

Why are they added to git in the first place and how do I avoid it.

Comment: What do you do to stage changes?

Comment: I start making a project on GitHub (or GitLab), do a checkout in PyCharm, add a bit of code. Unversioned files are colored red in the file list, black are unchanged and changed are green. Then clicking Commit (Command K / Windows K) and in the commit box I make sure only files I want to push to GitHub are selected. I enter a commit message and click the Commit dropdown button and in there Commit and Push. I'm not sure when they appear, but seems as PyCharm workfiles. And those are colored either green og black (= versioned) automatically instead of red and selected in the Commit and push box.