# How to delete a file in remote repository ONLY?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git: Remove a file from the repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

I wish to delete files from remote repository without deleting the files from local copy. Is there a way to do this in git?

The reason is: I am working on a project at early stage. I committed some files which should not be in the repository, so I added those files into `.gitignore`. If I remove those files from my local copy, the program will not work.

Thanks everyone. THis question is duplicating "[Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)"

Comment: Create a new branch, delete the files, and push

Comment: And then check out the original branch. Howard: Why are you making things difficult?

Comment: Move the file out of your working copy, delete the file in the index, commit, and move it back.

Comment: thanks Thilo, that is a very good idea. I am still learning git and guess my brain was trying to do things in git way.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use this command

```
git rm --cached <filename>
git rm --cached -r <dir_name>
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository"
git push origin master
```

This removes the ***filename*** from the index, without touching your working tree.

Comment: Yep... Duplicate question, thanks Thilo.

Comment: And bad answer, too. This one is for removing from the local repo.

Comment: thats not remote only