# Git: Remove files/folders from repository, but not from git clones when running git pull

Tags: git

I've added and committed a wrong folder. After fixing the .gitignore file, I need to remove those files from the repository, but I don't want those files to be deleted when I run `git pull` on the server.

I've tried the `--cached` flag as suggested here [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesy)

but it just doesn't work. I remove the file by `rm --cached file`. I commit the fact that is deleted. But when I `git pull` it removes that file from the server.

**Updated Example: SF2 parameters file (should be ignored, as it differs from machine to machine)**

- `app/config/parameters.yml` - a file that should be ignored in .gitignore
- is accidentally pushed into the repository
- fix the .gitignore file
- i need to remove it from the repository, but when I perform `git pull` on the server the file should not be removed.
- in this example it's very simple with just one file to manually backup on the server, git pull (the file is removed), restore the backup.
- but in my case there are a lot of different folders/files.

**By server I mean a clone of the repository, not the repository itself. It's just another machine with the repository cloned**

**Updated Short Explanation:**

Let's consider `repo-server | local-machine | deploy-server` .. I want to remove via `local-machine` some files from the repository (if another `local-machine-2` `git clone` the repository it doesn't get these files), **BUT** when I update the `deploy-server` via `git pull` I don't want those files to be removed from the `deploy-server`

Comment: Pulling doesn't change what is on the server. Do you mean pushing?

Comment: @bengoesboom - i'll update my question with more details in a couple of minutes. maybe it's not too clear

Comment: So you have repos `you | common | server` push/pulling across the vbars, and you want to erase all trace of the oopsie from the commit histories without deleting the flotsam from the server worktree, yes?

Comment: @jthill - let's consider `repo-server | local-machine | deploy-server` .. I want to remove via `local-machine` some files from the repository (if another `local-machine-2` `git clone` the repository doesn't get these files), BUT when I update the `deploy-server` via `git pull` I don't want those files to be removed from the `deploy-server` -- does this make sense?

Comment: @alex.dominte Add that to the question description. It makes sense now, but didn't make earlier.

Comment: So the error was committed in `local-machine` and pushed or pulled into `repo-server` and `deploy-server`?  (edit: I presume other repos will clone from `repo-server`, just checking here)

Comment: @jthill - yes the `wrong` files were committed and pushed to the server already, and pulled to the `deploy-server` and also a lot time ago I assume, I just stumble upon them now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you have three options here.

1) Use `update-index` with `--assume-unchanged` flag

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged app/config/parameters.yml
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged app/config/parameters.yml #Undo effect of previous command
```

You won't be removing the file from your git repo, but will be ignoring any local changes to it using this one.

Problem with this is, if any upstream commits update these files, git will abort the pull and thow up an error saying, `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge`. You *might* remember right now that you ran this command, but some time later, you won't, and might have a hard time figuring what is wrong.

2) Use git [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

For using submodules, you will have to completely remove the folders (say `app/config`) from the parent repo

```
git rm -r --cached app/config/
```

and create a new repo inside app/config/

Potential problems - 1) multiple submodules might be required depending on your app structure 2) If all that is changing are config files, this will be a definite overkill in terms of headaches you will face.

3) Use nested git repositories

In this one, you create a git repo inside the first one

```
cd ~/Desktop/project
git rm -r --cached app/config/
echo app/config >> .gitignore
cd app/config
git init && git add . && git commit -m "config paramters"
```

The difference between 2 & 3 is that with git submodules, you can get the exact relationship among the repos, but with nested repos, you will miss out on that information.

Also you will need to create an extra git repo for each such folder in submodules, but you can use a single extra repo to synchronise all such changes using a shell script.

Comment: +1 - for the detailed answer and suggested solutions, but I'm sure you understand that those solutions are way too complex for an apparently simple problem. thanks