# Remove pushed files from Git repo

Tags: git

I have pushed up two directories with to my Git Bitbucket repo, that I now wish to remove/delete.

How I'm a suppose to make those changes? I already tried with:

```
git rm -rf --cached files 
git commit -a -m "Deleted files" 
git push origin master
```

What I recon here is that it only removed the files from my working directory but left what it was in Bitbucket as it was.

Comment: Maybe you could revert the commit that added those directories?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can revert the commit, which you used to push those directories by the following commands

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

assuming the unwanted commit is at top of HEAD.

If it is lying before some commits, try this

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

which reverts the changes specified by the fourth last commit in HEAD. (You need to change the number '3' based on the position of your unwanted commit.)

And check `git status`. You should be able to see those unwanted directory as your local changes, which is yet to be committed.

Thanks!!

Comment: @nicoX., If you find this solution is helpful, please don't hesitate to "accept" this answer. so that, it would be helpful for future readers too!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem not long ago and I solved it using interactive rebasing.

What you do is find the commit hash of the commit before the committed you would like to change. Let say that hash is `376c762c1b28f927595010e98e4ee82d6bc63de3`

```bash
# first git checkout the correct branch
git rebase -i 376c762c1b28f927595010e98e4ee82d6bc63de3
```

You then get a list of all the commits after the commit of the commit hash, with a part of the commit message.

```bash
pick 376c762 Commit with wrong file
pick e145ef2 Fourth before last commit
pick d969e5b Third before last commit
pick 7b92c09 Second before last commit
pick db1dea3 First before last commit
pick ff120d6 Most recent commit message

# Rebase 621d70a..ff120d6 onto 621d70a (6 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
...
```

What you can do here is change the word before the commit to `edit` instead of `pick`. In our case:

```bash
edit 376c762 Commit with wrong file
```

Then you save the file and exit, `Ctr + X`, `Y` and `Enter` if you are using nano.

You are then dropped back to the command line just after the commit. You can the do the following to undo the previous commit. The files and you will have the uncommitted changes. The prompt will show the first 7 characters of the commit hash of the commit you are currently in.

```bash
git restore HEAD^
```

Then you can either remove/add/change files from the commit, add and commit the change. To continue the rebase you then do:

```bash
get rebase --continue
```

If the same files are changed in later commits you could get conflicts you have to fix  and commit before you can `--continue`. When the rebase is complete you will be

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the files in the remote branch by pushing to it an empty local branch -

Say you want to remove the `origin`'s branch `trial`, then you'd do `git push origin :trial`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually deleted the files

```
rm -rf directory-to-remove/
```

Then remove from git:

```
git rm -r --cached directory-to-remove/
```

Finally commit & push:

```
git commit -a -m "Deleted files"
git push origin master
```

Assuming your current branch is master.

Comment: It's images of a Wordpress site. I don't actually want the remove the directories, but there is no need that I have pushed 2GB of images to Bitbucket.

Comment: Then you should add a .gitignore file in those directories and add this to git. The content of the file can be * 

`git add directory/.gitignore`

Comment: I included them in .gitignore afterwards.

Comment: You can exclude all the file in a specific directory by adding a '*' in the .gitignore file in the specific directory.

First remove from cache
`git rm -rf --cached directory-to-remove/`

Make sure you're adding the .gitignore file 
`git add directory/.gitignore`

You can check w/ `git status` which files are staged for commit.