# Delete tmp files with git

Tags: git

I'm using git in my project but I'm new with this control version and I now have a doubt (problem) and I don't know like resolve it. I did commit to my local repo and remote repo also but I didn't ignore some files ie: .classpath, .project, . setting,... also I didn't ignore folders like: target, servers,.. and now they are in my repors and I want to ignore them but I have added .gitignore file with this exceptions and they are in my repors. How could I ignore them and what they are not in my repors?

Thanks.

Comment: So are you asking, how do you remove existing file in your repository if you add new rules to your .gitignore?

Comment: Add the paths you want to ignore to `.gitignore`, schedule the removal of those files and dirs using `git rm --cached`, commit, push and that's all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)