# Git rm --cache on one server results in physical deletion on another

Tags: git

I wanted to stop tracking a file, so I added it to `.gitignore` and did `git rm --cache thefile.php` to try to accomplish that. All seemed well. The file remained, but was no longer tracked. I pushed to Github.

Now another machine with the repo has pulled from Github and seen this:

```
root@server [/home/butkus/public_html]# git pull
Password for 'https://billybutkus@github.com':
Updating 42e1727..2e0aef4
Fast-forward
 .../path/to/file.php    | 13 -------------
 1 file changed, 13 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 path/to/file.php
root@server [/home/butkus/public_html]#
```

File is now actually deleted rather than just ignored. What did I do wrong?

This amazingly well upvoted answer tells me I did it exactly right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143800/631764

But I sure didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You did it right. There is no way around the fact that other users will receive it as a deletion; they can restore the file by doing `git checkout <commit> <filename>`, where "commit" is the commit that last had the file.

Comment: I am just surprised that git would do *anything* to a file that is in `.gitignore`. That just doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @ButtleButkus: git treats ignored files as "not required, may destroy at any time".  There is currently no way to tell git that some file is precious, but not version-controlled.

Comment: Ok, so I check out that file and now it is in the list of files to be committed. But I don't want to commit it. Should I just remove it from cache again?

Comment: Yes, or you can do `git reset head <filename>`. BTW, one gotcha is that if anyone checks out a branch/commit that has that file, their local copy will get overwritten with that file, with no warnings from git. Then when they checkout a commit where the file has been removed from source control, their local copy will be removed.