# exclude from tracking with .gitignore not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to remove all files in "js" folder from being tracked.

Here is my .gitignore:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp


# dependencies

# IDEs and editors
/.idea

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage/*
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# js
js/


#System Files
.DS_Store

node_modules/
bower_components/
.sass-cache/
images/
app/test/reportscreenshots/
app/test/report/
```

Note the `js/` it is not removing files in that folder from being tracked. Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Why does my .gitignore not exclude files in "js" folder from being tracked?

Comment: Did you previously add that JS folder to your repository?  If so, then you will need to use `git rm --cached` before you can ignore it.

Comment: Try `git rm --cached js/**/*.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the folder was already tracked before, adding it to .gitignore won't untracked it.

You will also need to remove the file/directory from your git repo

`git rm --cached -r mydirectory`

`--cached` will remove it from gitrepo but not from the server. From [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)

After that, if you `git status`, you will see the deleted folder in the status. You will need to commit your deletion.