# how to get rid of projectname\.vs\projectname\v15\sqlite3\storage.ide

Tags: tfs, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

I've been using visual studio 2015 for a while now and recently upgraded to vs2017.  I'm storing my project on team foundation and often have 2 visual studio instances open, (to different solutions both stored on the same TFS)

Ever since I upgraded to vs2017 a new file has been added to each project: projectname\.vs\projectname\v15\sqlite3\storage.ide This file is constantly modified even though I never reference it in my code and don't use sqlite anywhere. This causes 2 problems:

1.) Every time I check in pending changes, it's modifying this file.  I've tried cloaking the .vs folder, I've tried deleting the contents of that folder on the TFS. It doesn't care. That file is always on my pending changes list. (I can exclude it, but it shouldn't be there.)

2.) More importantly my 2 instances of visual studio are trying to access each other's storage.ide files and throwing errors occasionally because they are in use.

What is creating this sqlite instance to show up in my projects?

If I can't remove it completely, how can I get it to play nice with TFS and multiple Visual Studio instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this question: [What is the "storage.ide" file beneath my Visual Studio solution folder, and what is "persistent storage"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016619/what-is-the-storage-ide-file-beneath-my-visual-studio-solution-folder-and-wha) , seems you could excluded this file added in source control.

> Everything in the `.vs` folder **should be excluded from your source
>   repository.** It is a folder created by Visual Studio for storing user
>   specific information. Previously there was a `.suo` file which held
>   this data.The change came from a [UserVoice
>   suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6079923-store-project-related-information-in-vs-folder-to).

Just use `.tfignore` just like `.gitignore` to [customize which files are ignored by version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control), note this will not influence the files already in source control. You need first delete or destroy the files in source control first and check in the new created `.tfingore` file. There next time when pending changes generated, the `projectname\.vs\projectname\v15\sqlite3\storage.ide`  will auto excluded by VS.

About how to create and add `.tfingore` you could refer my answer in this question: [What is the "storage.ide" file beneath my Visual Studio solution folder, and what is "persistent storage"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016619/what-is-the-storage-ide-file-beneath-my-visual-studio-solution-folder-and-wha)

Comment: ok this seems to work, but why didn't cloaking the folder? How is that different from .tfignore?

Comment: @BrianHeward Cloaking is the process of defining which folders or files should be **ignored the workspace on your development machine.** It will not influence other machines or other co-workers, they could still check in the .vs folders. Moreover, you could only cloaked files/folders already in source control. If you want to use cloak option, you need to check in the .vs folder to TFS (without any files or sub-folders) and then do the cloaked operation.