# Visual Studio creates gibberish folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to develop with C#.

Sometimes Visual Studio creates a folder with a gibberish name when I build a solution, like

```
C:\FNTJ1nkhh1X4r0gk3geH5yIYY8=
```

This folder only contains the subfolder `sqlite3\v1` which in turn contains the following files

- db.lock
- storage.ide
- storage.ide-shm
- storage.ide-wal

If such a folder is created, it is created for one certain solution, other solutions don't show that behaviour. Deleting the folder or recreating the solution doesn't help.

To rule them out I already disabled all extensions in Visual Studio but the problem remains.

I've also compared the affected solution file with an unaffected one but didn't find something suspicious.

Has anyone else experienced this and what could be the reason?

Comment: Well, that's pretty awful, smells like another agile bug.  These files are *supposed* to be stored in the hidden `.vs` subdirectory of the solution.  Make sure you can see hidden files to find out what might be wrong with it, in Explorer use View > Show/Hide section > Hidden items checkbox.

Comment: @HansPassant no, that's not it; both the affected solution and the not affected only contain a `.suo` file in the `.vs` directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016619/what-is-the-storage-ide-file-beneath-my-visual-studio-solution-folder-and-wha

Comment: Hm, probably Microsoft changed that between VS 2017 and VS 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [@HansPassant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035876/visual-studio-creates-gibberish-folder#comment114980478_65035876) I dug a bit further and found that the folder should be located under

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Roslyn\Cache\RemoteWorkspace
```

Searching for this location led me to [this forum post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1151420/servicehubroslyncodeanalysisserviceexe-creates-jun.html) which confirms this to be a bug in Visual Studio which should be fixed in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 preview 3.