# Deleting untracked files from Github

Tags: git, github

I've edited my gitignore to ignore some files (like .gradle, .idea) but how can i delete this files from github?
https://github.com/hakkikaancaliskan/NetHesap.git

Comment: Delete the file, push the commit, then add to .gitignore. If you want to remove it from history completely, easier to just start over sometimes.

Comment: [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143796/7976758). [How to remove/delete a file from commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make it in a different order:

1. Delete files from disk physically
2. Add deleted files into index: `git add . -A`
3. `git commit -m'files deleted'`
4. Edit `.gitignore` now