# Deleting files locally but not from online github repo

Tags: git, github, delete-file

It is probably a silly question, but I am new to github. I uploaded a very large dataset and I want to remove it from my laptop because of storage issues, but I still need it online for the users of the repo.
Is it possible to remove a file from the local repository but not from the online repo?

It is basically the opposite problem than [this very popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have pushed your data upstream to GitHub, you can safely delete it locally. Data on GitHub won't be affected unless you do something like

```
git rm <file>
git commit -m "deleted file"
git push
```

In which case it removes the file from the remote repository.

Comment: .. and then you can add it to .git/info/exclude to tell git not to re-download it on a `git pull` or similar, i think