# Difference between git rm & git rm --cached

Tags: git

According to [git rm doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#_description) ,

> Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index.
>   git rm will not remove a file from just your working directory.

Also,

> **--cached** : Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left
>   alone.

Now , I found a difference in the way they are changing working tree and index where I feel it does not matches the definition above.

First I ran `git rm --cached` and I saw this :

```
$ git rm --cached  src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java
rm 'src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java'

$ git status

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java
```

We can see the change as untracked file and in staged area.

*Why we have file in untracked area when the file change is in staging area ?*

Instead of that , If I had ran `git rm` , this is what I would got :

```
$ git rm src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java
rm 'src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java'

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    src/main/java/com/kang/pagination/PaginationResult.java
```

*Note that here we don't have untracked file. Why ?*

Comment: git rm alone, actually deletes physically your file... where --cached not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit notwithstanding, the answer to your question is exactly explained by what the commands do (not the commands' internal working).

Perhaps the confusion stems from understanding how to interpret `git status`.  An "untracked file' is a file in the worktree that is not in the index.  (To be listed in the default `status` output, it also must not be ignored.)

So if you start with a clean worktree, that means any file in the worktree is also in the index - so not untracked.

But then if you `git rm --cached` the file, it is removed from the index while being left alone in the worktree.  That means there is now a file in the wokrtree that is not in the index, so unless that path is ignored, it's going to be shown as an untracked file - even though nothing in the worktree itself changed.

That is different from `git rm` (without the `--cached` argument) not in terms of internal workings, but rather in terms of what the command does. This command *also removes the file from the worktree*; in this case there is not, at the end, a file in the worktree but not in the index (an untracked file).

Answer (score 2):

> Why we have file in untracked area when the file change is in staging area ?

Because you've used `git rm --cached` which removes the file from the staging area, but leaves the file on disk.  Since there is now no file in the repository, that file on disk *must* be untracked.

> Note that here we don't have untracked file. Why ?

Because the file doesn't exist on disk.  Therefore it couldn't possibly be untracked because it doesn't exist.

Imagine that after running `git rm` (before committing that changeE) that you *recreate a new file with the same name*.  Running `git status` will tell you that file is untracked, just as if you had created *any* new file that wasn't in the index.  This is the scenario that you've just emulated by running `git rm --cached`.