# Git is pushing up files despite gitignore and clear cache

Tags: git

I made a mistake and mispelt the name of my .gitignore file and when I went to push up to Github I realised I was also pushing up everything in my `node_modules` directory. I cancelled the command (ctrl + c) and fixed the .gitignore and ran `git rm -r --cached .`.

Running `git status` then showed only the changes to my .gitignore file so I commited them and then when to push up. However, during the `git push` I noticed the `node_module` files were still being pushed up.

Again I cancelled the command (ctrl + c) and ran `git reset --hard HEAD^`, re-added and re-committed, but again it seemed I was pushing up the `node_module` files.

Becuase I cancelled the push part-way through these files seem to be stuck in limbo.

Is there some way I can fix this so I can merge to github without pushing up my `node_module` files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` works for files not yet `add`ed, but not for files that are already tracked.

You may have to use `git filter-branch` to [remove those files from your Git local history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_removing_file_every_commit).

After that, a force push is needed, because you have modified the history.

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore wont work for files or folders  that are already pushed (inside a branch);
edit git ignore directly in repo, delete  files, and then pull to local;
remove files in local