# Removing an already commited and pushed file from git without deleting it

Tags: git, rm

I have a some files which I want to remove from git, but I don't want the files to be deleted, either locally or on other developers machines.

(These are files which should never have been in the repo, but I hadn't added them to .gitignore in time.)

Currently, my procedure is:

1. `echo "filename" >> .gitignore`
2. `cp filename filename.safe`
3. `git rm filename`
4. `git commit -a -m"removing filename from repo"`
5. `mv filename.safe filename`
6. Ask the other developers to `cp filename filename.safe` too.
7. `git push origin main`
8. Tell the other developers to `git pull; mv filename.safe filename`.

This procedure is very fragile, requiring correct timing and good communication.

Is there a safer way to remove a file from a git repo, without it being deleted on my machine or others'?

I have seen: [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste) but my files are already committed and pushed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+files+from+repository+don%27t+remove+from+server

Comment: Short answer: No, there is no way. What you do is the only way.