# gitignore cannot ignore folders from last commit

Tags: git, pycharm, gitignore

I try to ignore .idea directory when commit and push to remote repository. I set my .gitignore file in following way:

```
### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
```

But when I committed and pushed to tfs repository, I found the .idea folder is still pushed to repo.

Is there anyway to remove .idea folder from repository and ignore it in future commit and push?

Note: I have already committed and pushed to remote repository without setting up .gitignore file. I think the .idea folder in repo is from last commit.

[image]

Comment: It's ignoring _changes_. It won't remove files you already committed.

Comment: Did  you `git rm` that directory? Or if you want it to stay locally, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste

Comment: You can remove the folder anytime you like to prevent it from appearing in *future* commits. Removing it from *past* commits requires quite a bit of intrusive history editing.

Comment: `git rm --cached .idea` stages the directory (specifically, all files contained *in the directory*, which is all Git cares about) for removal without removing the directory itself from the working directory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you tell me how to resolve it please? I have no experience setting gitignore before

Comment: @chepner Thanks! it works. idea removed from git repository, and after I pushed it to remote, idea removed from remote repository as well.