# How to stop tracking a file without deleting it on Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072213/how-to-stop-tracking-a-file-without-removing-it-from-repo) which discusses a solution for `git`, and found [this thread](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/How-to-stop-tracking-a-file-without-deleting-the-file-td797836.html) on the mailing list for Mercurial (the thread is four years old though)

The solution proposed in the mailing list is to use `hg rm -Af file` (and they leave open the possibility of implementing this behavior as a new, more intuitive option). I'm wondering if that option exists now.

Also, if I try the command above:

```
> hg rm -Af my_file
> hg st
R my_file
```

there is an `R` next to `my_file`, but the file `my_file` is technically on disk, and I have told Mercurial to stop tracking it, so why am I getting `R` next to it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just use `hg forget` or maybe add the file to your `.hgignore` file

And to answer the last question about the `R` in `my_file`. If you see the help for `hg rm --help`:

> hg remove [OPTION]... FILE...
>
> aliases: rm
>
> remove the specified files on the next commit
>
> ```
> Schedule the indicated files for removal from the current branch.
>
> This command schedules the files to be removed at the next commit. To undo
> a remove before that, see "hg revert". To undo added files, see "hg
> forget".
>
> Returns 0 on success, 1 if any warnings encountered.
> ```
>
> options:
>
> -A --after         record delete for missing files
>    -f --force         remove (and delete) file even if added or modified
>    -I --include       PATTERN [+] include names matching the given patterns
>    -X --exclude       PATTERN [+] exclude names matching the given patterns
>
> [+] marked option can be specified multiple times
>
> use "hg -v help remove" to show more info

As you can see you are forcing the deletion of that file and that's why you can see the `R` (Removed)

Comment: Thanks I think the reason why I got confused is because `hg forget myfile` (which seems to be an alias for `hg rm -Af myfile`) **marks** the file so that hg stops tracking it **after committing** (which is why the Hg shows `R` next to file until I commit)

Comment: Not working for me.  I do the forget, the remove, and the commit, and after that, every damn time I recompile my project, test.exe keeps showing up at the commit as modified.