# Mercurial hg ignore does not work properly

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Situation

```
$ cat .hgignore
.hgignore

$ hg status
M file1
M file2
M src/project.xml
```

I don't want to track the `project.xml` so I run

```
echo "project.xml" >> .hgignore
```

and the result is

```
$ cat .hgignore
.hgignore
project.xml

$ hg status
M .hgignore
M file1
M file2
M src/project.xml
```

So the `.hgignore` is now as modified even though it shouldn't be tracked and nothing happend with the `project.xml`. What does this mean?

Comment: Are you sure that the `src/project.xml` wasn't already in the files tracked by `hg`?

Comment: @Atropo It was... But I thought putting it into `.hgignore` will remove it from there.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: [How to stop tracking a file without deleting it on mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482538/how-to-stop-tracking-a-file-without-deleting-the-file-on-mercurial).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You wrote:

"**M** src/project.xml"

which means that `src/project.xml` is under version control.
A file already under version control cannot be ignored! The
`.hgignore` file is for ignoring files that are untracked (status
will show a "**?**").

You have two solutions to ignore your file:

1. You can either "`hg forget`" the file, the opposite of "`hg add`" (i.e.,
   telling Mercurial not to track this file anymore), or
2. You can use the ”`-X`” option as a default for `status/diff/commit`
   in your `.hg/hgrc` configuration file, e.g.,

   [defaults]
   status = -X `<file>`
   diff = -X `<file>`
   commit = -X `<file>`

which will tell hg not to include this file in the use of status, diff, and commit.

Comment: I think the `hg forget` definitely is the better option here. A VCS should not just silently ignore a modified file under version control, that WILL lead to trouble in the future when you forget about this and expect hg to just track changes to the file without thinking about it.