# Mercurial: how to untrack file from added filelist?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

A file was added accidentally to a Mercurial repository. How can I untrack it so that it is not included in the next commit?  I'd also be interested to know how to accomplish the same task in `git`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop tracking a file without deleting it on Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482538/how-to-stop-tracking-a-file-without-deleting-it-on-mercurial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to become aquainted with

```
hg forget FILENAME
```

It works for both, already committed and uncommitted files.